# Javascript prototype chain vs scope chain

Tags: javascript, scope, lexical-scope, prototype-chain

I created a javascript code snippet and here's the link to [visualiser](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=function%20Foo%28name%29%20%7B%0A%20%20this.name%20%3D%20name%0A%20%20this.speak%20%3D%20function%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%28this.name%29%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20init%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20function%20init_%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20foo%20%3D%20new%20Foo%28%27foo%27%29%0A%20%20%20%20foo.hear%20%3D%20function%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%28%27i%20can%20hear%27%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20bar%20%3D%20new%20Foo%28%27bar%27%29%0A%20%20%20%20bar.look%20%3D%20function%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%28%27i%20can%20look%27%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20foo.speak%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20bar.speak%28%29%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20init_%28%29%0A%7D%0A%0Ainit%28%29%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=12&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=js&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

```
function Foo(name) {
  this.name = name
  this.speak = function() {
    console.log(this.name)
  }
}

function init() {
  function init_() {
    var foo = new Foo('foo')
    foo.hear = function() {
      console.log('i can hear')
    }
    var bar = new Foo('bar')
    bar.look = function() {
      console.log('i can look')
    }
    foo.speak()
    bar.speak()
  }
  
  init_()
}

init()
```

I have several questions:

1. In which stage is prototype object aka `Foo.prototype` created? When the interpreter loads `Foo` to global scope or when `new Foo()` is been called for the first time, or in any other stage? In which lexical scope is its reference stored? (since there's no such ref in visualiser)
2. Should `foo` and `bar` share the method `speak()` which belongs to `Foo.prototype` rather than owning their own copies as shown in visualiser?
3. Are prototype chain and scope chain unrelated? For example, when `foo.speak()` is called, first we trace scope chain to get value of `foo`, then prototype chain to get `speak()`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In which stage is prototype object aka `Foo.prototype` created? When the interpreter loads `Foo` to global scope?

Yes, the prototype object is created when the `Foo` function is created.

> In which lexical scope is its reference stored? (since there's no such ref in visualiser)

In none at all. It's stored only in a property of `Foo`.

> Should `foo` and `bar` share the method `speak()` which belongs to `Foo.prototype` rather than owning their own copies as shown in visualiser?

Yes. It seems like that visualiser was built for Python and does not support prototype links at all.

> Are prototype chain and scope chain unrelated? For example, when `foo.speak()` is called, first we trace scope chain to get value of `foo`, then prototype chain to get `speak()`?

Yes, yes.

Notice however that the visualiser you found does not display the scope chain, it only does display the call stack, and does very bad at visualising lexical scope and closures correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bergi! Just being curious that does python instance deep copy everything from class?

Comment: IIRC, yes, Python classes do for practical purposes copy all class members onto instances. Or only data members? I'm a bit rusty on that. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects says "*When a non-data attribute of an instance is referenced, the instance’s class is searched.*"